# recalculate delay from fsdb file

Tags: simulation, vlsi, eda

I came across [`hsim`](http://www.synopsys.com/Tools/Verification/AMSVerification/CircuitSimulation/HSIM/Pages/default.aspx) help menu and I found these two switches pretty interesting.

```
-fsdb <filename>               specify fsdb file for measure & fft
-wdf <filename>                specify wdf file for measure & fft
```

so my question is : Can I reuse the `fsdb` file generated, to recalculate delay, I have to do iterations by altering threshold of measurements and nothing change in device profiles.
for e.g.
**Iteration 1**

```
.measure tran jig_t_wfloat TRIG V(float) VAL=VH050 TD='VEC_INT * 23' FALL=1 TARG V(wl) VAL=VH090 RISE=1
```

**Iteration 2**

```
.measure tran jig_t_wfloat TRIG V(float) VAL=VH050 TD='VEC_INT * 48' FALL=1 TARG V(wl) VAL=VH080 RISE=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution from this [Hsim tutorial](http://www.ece.utah.edu/~kstevens/4900/reports/hsim_simulation_manual.pdf)

> -fsdb *out_file.fsdb* Specify -fsdb to perform .fft and .measure analyses in the post-processing step. After regular simulation is
>   completed, the simulation output is stored in a .fsdb file, such as
>   out_file.fsdb. You can add .measure and/or .fft statements to the
>   netlist file and invoke HSIM to perform .fft and measure analyses
>   without repeating the simulation.

thus all I needed to do is

`hsim -i <same_input_spice_code_with_altered_meas_commad> -fsdb <previous_generated_fsdb> -o <output>`

Its pretty helpful for fast iterations, where there is only change in `.meas` statements.
but do take care that all **probes** are generated in `fsdb` previously